# ¿Por qué Python me da error al instalar estas librerías?

Tags: python, inteligencia-artificial

Estoy iniciando en la Inteligenia Artificial y en mi proyecto estoy utilizando YoloV8, al instalar la libreria `ultralytics` me aparece el siguiente error:

```
    ultralytics 0.0.29 depends on torch>=1.7.0
    ultralytics 0.0.28 depends on torch>=1.7.0
    ultralytics 0.0.27 depends on torch>=1.7.0
    ultralytics 0.0.26 depends on torch>=1.7.0
    ultralytics 0.0.25 depends on torch>=1.7.0
    ultralytics 0.0.24 depends on torch>=1.7.0
    ultralytics 0.0.23 depends on torch>=1.7.0
    ultralytics 0.0.22 depends on torch>=1.7.0
    ultralytics 0.0.21 depends on torch>=1.7.0
    ultralytics 0.0.19 depends on torch>=1.7.0
    ultralytics 0.0.18 depends on torch>=1.7.0
    ultralytics 0.0.17 depends on torch>=1.7.0
    ultralytics 0.0.16 depends on torch>=1.7.0
    ultralytics 0.0.14 depends on torch>=1.7.0
    ultralytics 0.0.13 depends on torch>=1.7.0

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
```

El comando que utilizo es

```
pip install ultralytics
```

Entiendo que me pida instalar torch pero al buscarlo e instalar la librería, me entregó el siguiente error:

Ingreso el comando en la consola

```
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118
```

Y la consola me arroja el siguiente mensaje

```
PS C:\Users\Informatica\Desktop\DeteccionPatentes> pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in indexes: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch
```

Intenté reinstalar completamente Python y tampoco se solucionó, eliminé Path y lo coloqué nuevamente, antes funcionaba correctamente pero ahora dejó de funcionar entregando ese error...

Comment: ¿Usas Python 3.12? Tendría que comprobarlo, pero es posible que torch no lo soporte aun. Si es tu caso, prueba instalando Python 3.11.

Comment: Efectivamente aun no esta soportado: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/110436